# how to check if entry exists before inserting in sql table

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table called `Panels` as below with the following entry as of now.

```
---Panel table

    p_id    sequence    p_type  
      1       2          '3a'
 ... and many more rows
```

I am using the following query to insert into the `Panels` table a new entry with `p_type='4a'`. In order to create the new entry, I will use the `p_type='3a'`. My issue is that how can I check if the entry for p_type='4a' already exists in the table before doing the INSERT INTO.

Trying to find a solution online, I found a template code such as the follows.

```
if not exists (select column_1 from table_name where column_1 = value)
begin
    insert statement here
end
go
```

My Insert logic is as the following:

```
INSERT INTO Panels (p_id,sequence,p_type) 
        SELECT p_id,sequence,'4a'
        FROM Panels
        WHERE p_type='3a'
```

The issue I am having is that I dont know how to intergrate the template code logic I have above with my INSERT INTO statement. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `not exists` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Panels (p_id,sequence,p_type) 
SELECT p_id,sequence,'4a'
  FROM Panels p
 WHERE p_type='3a'
   And not exists
           (select 1 from Panels pp
             WHERE pp.p_type='4a' 
               and p.p_id = pp.p_id 
               and p.sequence = pp.sequence)
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Nope. But this is standard sql.

Comment: What is the 1 supposed to mean? I am a bit confused. May you add some clarity please?

Comment: 1 in exists. Nothing. You can use null or * there. Exists clause mainly checks if query returns any row or not.

Answer (score 1):

Don't check in advance, but let the database do it for you by implementing a UNIQUE constraint on it. Otherwise, there will always be a chance another thread inserts the row in between the check and the insert.

For example:

```
alter table panels add constraint uq1 (id, p_type);
```

Then, if an `INSERT` fails, then it the combination already existed.

Comment: how can I do it with using the issue I have? I dont want to use the constraint approach. I know it is a good one but I cannot modify this database, I need to use it as it is.